# C++ template nontype parameter arithmetic

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, template-specialization

I am trying to specialize template the following way:

```
template<size_t _1,size_t _2> // workaround: bool consecutive = (_1 == _2 - 1)>
struct integral_index_ {};
...
template<size_t _1>
struct integral_index_<_1, _1 + 1> { // cannot do arithmetic?
//struct integral_index_<_1, _2, true> { workaround
};
```

however I get compiler message error

```
the template argument list of the partial specialization includes a non
-type argument whose type depends on a template parameter.
```

what do my doing wrong?
thanks

I put workaround in comments.  Apparently I cannot do arithmetic in template specialization?  seems counterintuitive.

here is my final solution in the problem to be solved. Basically, consecutive index requires one multiplication only.

```
130 template<size_t _1,size_t _2, bool consecutive = (_1 == _2 - 1)>
131 struct integral_index_ {
132     template<typename T, typename U>
133     __device__
134     static T eval(const T (&N)[4], const U &index) {
135         T j = index/N[_1];
136         return ((index - j*N[_1])*range<0,_1>::multiply(N) +
137                 j*range<0,_2>::multiply(N));
138     }
139 };
140
141 template<size_t _1,size_t _2>
142 struct integral_index_<_1, _2, true> {
143     template<typename T, typename U>
144     __device__
145     static T eval(const T (&N)[4], const U &index) {
146         return index*range<0,_1>::multiply(N);
147     }
148 };
149
150 template<size_t _1,size_t _2, typename T, typename U>
151 __device__
152 T integral_index(const T (&N)[4], const U &index) {
153     return integral_index_<_1,_2>::eval(N, index);
154 }
```

Comment: A bit bigger picture would help here. You have to do a bit of design change to get the same effect. Also, the line numbers tend to get in the way. :)

Comment: @GMan I suppose I can use extra default argument, `bool consecutive = _1 == _2 - 1`?

Comment: I'm looking forward to seeing this one answered.  It will advance my understanding of the language.

Comment: @aaa: What are you hoping to do, though?

Comment: @GMan mapping multidimensional indices from flat index.  Consecutive index does not require integer divide I like to avoid

Comment: @aaa: I'm afraid I'm only on the edge of understanding what you meant by that. :) In any case, is this mapping done at run-time or compile-time? And, in suspicion of the former, is Boost available?

Comment: @aaa: An example of how you desire to use this would help.

Comment: @Gman I put program listing. I make it sound too complicated, it is not that involved.  Cannot use boost runtime functions, this is for GPU device

Comment: @aaa: Ah, I see. What you have seems to work pretty well, pretty clean too. :) You should post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am posting my solution is suggested by GMan

```
130 template<size_t _1,size_t _2, bool consecutive = (_1 == _2 - 1)>
131 struct integral_index_ {
132     template<typename T, typename U>
133     __device__
134     static T eval(const T (&N)[4], const U &index) {
135         T j = index/N[_1];
136         return ((index - j*N[_1])*range<0,_1>::multiply(N) +
137                 j*range<0,_2>::multiply(N));
138     }
139 };
140
141 template<size_t _1,size_t _2>
142 struct integral_index_<_1, _2, true> {
143     template<typename T, typename U>
144     __device__
145     static T eval(const T (&N)[4], const U &index) {
146         return index*range<0,_1>::multiply(N);
147     }
148 };
149
150 template<size_t _1,size_t _2, typename T, typename U>
151 __device__
152 T integral_index(const T (&N)[4], const U &index) {
153     return integral_index_<_1,_2>::eval(N, index);
154 }
```

Comment: You can get rid of the static `eval` and just make the value an actual static variable. That way you can access the value as a nested `::value` rather than calling a function (that still happens at runtime).

Comment: Depending what `multiply` does, maybe that expression can even be moved into an `enum`. (After eliminating the call, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
template<size_t _1,size_t _2>
struct integral_index_ {};

template<size_t _1>
struct integral_index_2 : public integral_index_<_1, _1+1> {
};
```

Comment: I am trying to specialize cases where second argument is one greater than first

Comment: Then he loses the effect he wanted.

Comment: hello
I just put something similar using third template parameter in the original post

Answer (score 1):

You can also move the condition from the primary template into the specialization. The trick is that while non-type parameters in sub-expressions aren't allowed in non-type specialization arguments, they *are* allowed in type arguments

```
template<bool C> struct bool_ { };

template<int _1, int _2, typename = bool_<true> >
struct mapping {
  // general impl
};

template<int _1, int _2>
struct mapping<_1, _2, bool_<(_1 + 1) == _2> > {
  // if consecutive
};

template<int _1, int _2>
struct mapping<_1, _2, bool_<(_1 * 3) == _2> > {
  // triple as large
};
```

Occassionally, people also use *SFINAE* for this. The following accesses `::type` which is only there if the condition is true. If it is false, the type is not there and *SFINAE* sorts out the specialization.

```
template<int _1, int _2, typename = void>
struct mapping {
  // general impl
};

template<int _1, int _2>
struct mapping<_1, _2, 
               typename enable_if<(_1 + 1) == _2>::type> {
  // if consecutive
};

template<int _1, int _2>
struct mapping<_1, _2, 
               typename enable_if<(_1 * 3) == _2>::type> {
  // triple as large
};
```

With `enable_if` being the following well-known template

```
template<bool C, typename R = void>
struct enable_if { };

template<typename R = void>
struct enable_if<true, R> { typedef R type; };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your attempting to specialize by value instead of type...

Comment: You can specialize by value. The problem is the arithmetic within the specialization.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that works for me: use a default argument for `_2` instead of trying to specialize.

```
template <size_t _1, size_t _2 = _1 + 1>
struct integral_index_ {};
```

Does that look like what you want?

Comment: aaa really wants to write a specialized version of the template, not just a default argument.

Anyway, he already found a nice workaround with the "bool consecutive = (_1 == _2 - 1)" trick :)